# Storing entries in a very large database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, saas

I am writing a Django application that will have entries entered by users of the site. Now suppose that everything goes well, and I get the expected number of visitors (unlikely, but I'm planning for the future). This would result in hundreds of millions of entries in a single PostgreSQL database.

As iterating through such a large number of entries and checking their values is not a good idea, I am considering ways of grouping entries together.

Is grouping entries in to sets of (let's say) 100 a better idea for storing this many entries? Or is there a better way that I could optimize this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Why would you want to iterate over the entries? Databases are great at searching, that's what they're for.

Comment: @DanielRoseman but surely doing the same operation several times a minute is a bad idea?

Comment: @techydesigner: have you tested it? Shouldn't be a problem at all. Modern databases are extremely good, any tricks you may think of will not be as good in comparison.

Comment: @DanielRoseman checking if the value belongs to the specified user ID. Would storing a list of the user's items and their IDs be faster?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I haven't got to that stage yet.

Comment: Storing hundreds of millions of rows in a database table and figuring out which of them belong to a user is what a database like Postgres _is for_. Your groups of 100 will definitely do worse than its indexes.

Comment: Let think after you get to that point right now traditional can handle it well.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Alright then... would this be expandable to a billion entries? Note this is in a single database - with the same database on multiple machines.

Comment: @giaosudau I would hate to get to that part and then have to shut down the servers for several hours - SaaS offline is not a good idea, especially considering that this website completely relies on a database.

Comment: @techydesigner: what the actual limits are depends on your exact structure, the kinds of queries you do how often, your hardware, how often things change, etc etc. As a rule you can't possibly imagine the exact problem you'll run into first when you need to scale at the start of the project. If you have some idea, then TEST THAT.

Comment: But at least, rest assured that by the time the problems become so large that you can't use Postgres, you'll be successful enough to have some employees deal with it. Now, the focus should be on getting there in the first place.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Realistically, entries would only be added, and they would only be a few bites in size - however, this discussion in the comments seems to be a good answer - I would appreciate it if you added it as an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store one at a time until you absolutely cannot anymore, then design something else around your specific problem.

SQL is a declarative language, meaning "give me all records matching X" doesn't tell the db server *how* to do this.  Consequently, you have a lot of ways to help the db server do this quickly even when you have hundreds of millions of records.  Additionally RDBMSs are optimized for this problem over a lot of years of experience so to a certain point, you will not beat a system like PostgreSQL.

So as they say, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

So let's look at two ways PostgreSQL might go through a table to give you the results.

The first is a sequential scan, where it iterates over a series of pages, scans each page for the values and returns the records to you.  This works better than any other method for very small tables.  It is slow on large tables.  Complexity is O(n) where n is the size of the table, for any number of records.

So a second approach might be an index scan.  Here PostgreSQL traverses a series of pages in a b-tree index to find the records.  Complexity is O(log(n)) to find each record.

Internally PostgreSQL stores the rows in batches with fixed sizes, as pages.  It already solves this problem for you.  If you try to do the same, then you have batches of records inside batches of records, which is usually a recipe for bad things.

Comment: Great answer mate. Very informative. Thanks very much!

Comment: btw, I work with dbs containing hundreds of millions of rows totalling 10TB+ in size.  There are cases where some sort of denormalized storage is helpful but at your stage you probably won't have an idea of what may actually bite you, and denormalizing for the future is usually a way to create problems